# Session is not working in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I have developed a project work in codeigniter. There is a login page in the website. When logging in, when clicking any of the menu items, it is redirecting to the login page. Also when reloading the home page after logging in, it is also redirecting to the login page.

```
public function profile() {
    $data = array();
    if($this->session->userdata('loggedIn') !== FALSE && $this->session->userdata('logType') == 'stu') {
            //echo 'okkkk!!!';die;
    $data = $this->session->all_userdata();
    $data['user_data'] = $this->data->getStuByIdDb($data['stu_id']);
    log_message('info','data '.print_r($data,TRUE));
        $this->load->view('stuProfileView',$data);
    }
            else{
                //echo 'okkkk';die;
        $this->load->view('stuLoginView');
    } 
}
```

A code of a particular menu profile is shown above. When clicking it goes to a controller named 'Stu' in which a function named profile() is coded which I have pasted above. I have autoloaded the session library. But the if statement session is not working. Can anyone suggest a solution for correcting this ?

Is this due to my server version issue ?

config.php

```
$config['sess_driver'] = 'database';
$config['sess_cookie_name'] = 'ci_session';
$config['sess_expiration'] = 7200;
$config['sess_save_path'] = 'ci_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_time_to_update'] = 300;
$config['sess_regenerate_destroy'] = FALSE;

$config['sess_use_database'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name'] = 'ci_sessions';
```

autoload.php

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session', 'encrypt');
```

controller file

```
public function authStu() {
    $rsp = array();
    $authStuData = array();
    $authStuData = $this->input->post(NULL, TRUE);
    log_message('info',print_r($authStuData,TRUE));     
    $rsp = $this->data->authStuDb($authStuData);
    log_message('info','rsp '.print_r($rsp,TRUE));
    if ($rsp['authStuStatus'] == TRUE){
        $rsp['status'] = TRUE;
        $rsp['msg'] =  "Student Valid";
        $rsp['statusID'] = 010;
        $rsp['data'] = NULL;

        $newdata = array(
            'stu_id'  => $rsp['stu_id'],
            'logType' => 'stu',
            'loggedIn' => TRUE
        );
        $this->session->set_userdata($newdata);

    }elseif($rsp['authStuStatus'] == FALSE){
        $rsp['status'] = FALSE;
        $rsp['msg'] =  "Sorry, this student doesn't exist";
        $rsp['statusID'] = 000;
        $rsp['data'] = NULL;
    }
    echo json_encode ($rsp);
}
```

In the above code , loggedIn session variable is set with the data. This is the function in the controller itself.

Comment: show code where you define all session

Comment: I have edited the post code. Please check

Comment: where you set $this->session->userdata('loggedIn') session value

Comment: not this , talking about where you r setting your session like loggedIn , by the way what ci version you are using

Comment: CI 3............I have pasted the code where session loggedIn is set with the data.

Comment: check if(isset($this->session->userdata('loggedIn') ){ //"redirect home"; }else{ //"redirect login";}

Comment: for CI 3 uses file type for session storage. make changes in config